# Resharper ASP intellisense information overflow

Tags: asp.net, webforms, resharper, intellisense, resharper-6.1

Is it possible to get resharper to list only the usable options for asp controls?

With the suggestion list now, I get all possible tags and classes which does not help me being efficient. Even though I write the asp tag I still get a lot of unusable info about asp objects.

Maybe it is possible to turnoff the resharper intellisense for html? The images below shows the difference

Standard Intellisense

[image: Standard Intellisense]

ReSharper Intellisense

[image: ReSharper Intellisense]

Comment: I found how to turn off resharper intellisense for html and server pages. But that is not really what I want to do. ReSharper ->Options -> IntelliSense ->General ->Limited Resharper IntelliSense. Check everything but "HTML (.html files and server pages)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you can't. This is a case where VS native IntelliSense wins.

You have the option to turn off HTML completion as you pointed out in your comment, and/or try [Smart Completion](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Coding_Assistance__Code_Completion__Smart.html) here and there, hoping that in certain code positions, it's able to filter out irrelevant completion items.

There are related feature requests in ReSharper issue tracker for example

- [IntelliSense focusing on most relevant properties in ASP.NET controls](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-220143)
- [Intellisense while editing content template](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-266504)

which you can vote for (and watch).

Comment: ASP .net developers need this fix!!! Problem with turning off HTML completion, or disabling ReSharper IntelliSense (moving smart auto-complete to ctrl+alt+space) is that you will not have nice auto-complete as example for <%$Resource:> elements. Even if you press ctrl+alt+space - there is no suggestion for resx files, only suggestion of keys for local resx, but if you turn on ReSharper IntelliSense as by default, there will be resx file name suggestion (i mean for different global resource files). At least group important tags and use this yellow native icon for them =(((